# Macro to Create combobox in Excel anywhere

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I want to create a Macro that allows comboboxes to be placed in every cell that I select. I am able to create a Macro places the combobox in the same cell, where I record it. It gives it a range, like "N15", so every time I execute the macro, the comboboxes stack up in the same cell. Since i am new in VB, i am requesting if someone can tell me the trick to place it in the active cell.

I have a reference cell link. I found a helpful person in one of the forums, who has supplied a code to "refresh" the links, when you copy-paste. It would be nice to just combine this along with the combobox.

When I add ActiveCell, it gives me an error: "Object doesn't support this property or method".

This the code the macro of a simple copy-paste creates:

```
Sub AAA()
'
' AAA Macro
'

'
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(-3, 1).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("ComboBox4")).Select
    Application.Run "ExcelTemplate_DayOne.xlsm!Sheet1.Test"
End Sub
```

The Range("A1") is what will ensure that every time i run the macro, the combobox will go and get added to that same cell. If I change Activesheet.Paste to ActiveCell.Paste, it gives me the above error, I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

To use the active cell, use `ActiveCell`

For example, to get the row of the active cell, use : `ActiveCell.Row`

To get the column : `ActiveCell.Column`

To put something in that very cell you could either do :

`ActiveCell = "SOMETHING!"`

OR :

`Cells( ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Columns ) = "SOMETHING TOO !"`